# No sound from speakers

Tags: speakers

I have problem with my speakers which were working fine until y'day

tried with another set of speakers but still no avail

Basic checks done:
the volume is not down
speakers are powered on

Further INfo
I had creative 5.1 until yesterday and now trying with normal PC speakers
I have creative sound card installed as well
the device manager does not throw any asterk marks or errors

ANy help?

Comment: When you say "volume is not down" do you mean in software or on the speakers?  What operating system are you using?  What version?

Comment: Checked the mute button? On both speakers, OS and application?

Comment: I meant the speaker is not in mute

Comment: OS: windows XP
checked mute button on speakers as well as machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just wanted to make note that the issue is fixed

I had to remove the soundcard and then fix it back
install the drivers for the card

Now the speakers are workin fine

Comment: Mark this as the answer please. :)